# Conditional SQL block evaluated even when it won't be executed

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

I'm working on writing a migration script for a database, and am hoping to make it idempotent, so we can safely run it any number of times without fear of it altering the database (/ migrating data) beyond the first attempt.

Part of this migration involves removing columns from a table, but inserting that data into another table first. To do so, I have something along these lines.

```
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableToBeModified')
        AND name = 'ColumnToBeDropped')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE MigrationTable (
        Id int,
        ColumnToBeDropped varchar
    );

    INSERT INTO MigrationTable
    (Id, ColumnToBeDropped)
    SELECT Id, ColumnToBeDropped
      FROM TableToBeModified;
END
```

The first time through, this works fine, since it still exists. However, on subsequent attempts, it fails because the column no longer exists. I understand that the entire script is evaluated, and I could instead put the inner contents into an `EXEC` statement, but is that really the best solution to this problem, or is there another, still potentially "validity enforced" option?

Comment: Another option is to put CREATE and INSERT into a sp.

Comment: Dynamic SQL would be simpler than abstracting away into a stored procedure.

Comment: @Balde I agree with Aaron, especially because this is a one-time script, and you would still need a rollout script for that stored procedure, so not really saving anything.

Comment: @srutzky I agree. Just saying "another option".

Comment: @Balde SPs are also validated, though, right? So wouldn't that potentially have the same issues?

Comment: Object references are validated when SP is executed, not when SP is created. If the SP only runs when the column exists, then no errors.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that the entire script is evaluated, and I could instead put the inner contents into an `EXEC` statement, but is that really the best solution to this problem

Yes. There are several scenarios in which you would want to push off the parsing validation due to dependencies elsewhere in the script. I will even sometimes put things into an `EXEC`, even if there are no current problems, to ensure that there won't be as either the rest of the script changes or the environment due to addition changes made after the current rollout script was developed. Minorly, it helps break things up visually.

While there can be permissions issues related to breaking ownership changing due to using Dynamic SQL, that is rarely a concern for a rollout script, and not a problem I have ever run into.

Comment: Your argument here seems to be all the things I'm hoping to avoid by using EXEC ;) `even if there aren't currently, preventing future` - isn't this destined to fail? Putting it into an exec means it won't be evaluated until a time it's actually executed, so you'll get unexpected runtime failure.

Comment: `permissions issues` -- if permissions change, again, that won't be apparent until a runtime failure occurs.

Comment: `break things up visually` -- not so much an issue, but why would I want that? Also, it's not syntax tested, so typos.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just concerned about those things in particular. It feels like taking "strongly typed sql" and removing the good pieces, like strong typing.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi There is really nothing to worry about here, and besides, not anything you could do about it anyway. The permissions thing was just a technical detail to mention, but not anything to concern a rollout script since you need to execute with a privileged account anyway.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi as far as evaluating at runtime goes, that is true for the entire script, this is just a means of encapsulation. With regards to catching errors, a) you should be testing the script in QA and UAT/Staging first to work out most errors, and b) you should be wrapping sections, as appropriate, in `TRY / CATCH` blocks to catch all other errors regardless of this specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

If we are not sure that the script will work or not specially migrating database.

However, For query to updated data related change, i will execute script with **BEGIN TRAN** and check result is expected then we need to perform **COMMIT TRAN** otherwise **ROLLBACK** transaction, so it will discard transaction.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I'm asking here. I'm not looking to "test" a specific transaction, I'm looking to create a script that can be run N number of times, where after the first time, the column will *for sure* not exist. It won't be executed manually either, fwiw, so I'm not sure how transactions will help that.